# How to scroll Notebooks list at the left to the currently opened page in OneNote?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2016

I have many notebooks and many pages inside them in OneNote. They are always expanded in my work. When I find some page by search, I am unable to locate appropriate section at left. I need to scroll long list manually and catch selected item by eye. Can I scroll to current page automatically?

There were no such ability in OneNote 2013 and it is apparently no one in OneNote 2016. What are they doing there?

**UPDATE**

Apparently question was not set clear. I mean I already found my page, I see it on screen. Now I wish to find it's tab or know at left, to see neighboring pages or parent page.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

1.On the ribbon, click the History tab.

2.In the Authors group, click Recent Edits.

3.On the menu that appears, click a timeframe.

4.Click a page name to view its contents.

This seems like the only way to do it. You can view your edits by the time you did it

Comment: No, this is not it. Suppose I already opened the page. I know it, I see it. Now I need to find it's tab at left. How to do this?

Comment: @Dims, After some thorough research, i have found that such a feature isn't available. i suppose you would have to ctrl + e. i am sorry for any inconvenience caused